# how to get the timing report register to register and input to output in STA?

Tags: synthesis, timing-analysis, sdc

I'm trying to get the timing report of STA. As I know, basically, there are 4 types of timing paths.

1. Input to register
2. Register to register
3. Register to output
4. Input to output

[image: 4 timing paths]

Practically, I want to know what command do I need to get the 4 timing reports?

So far, I know how to make 2 paths:

```
report_timing -from [all_inputs] >report_from_all_input.txt

report_timing -to [all_outputs] > report_to_all_output.txt
```

but the other things not.

Would you help me how to get the timing report of 4 paths in Design Compiler?

## update

I come across the below message when I run with below command.

```
report_timing -from [all_inputs]    -to [all_registers]  > report_input2reg.txt
report_timing -from [all_registers] -to [all_registers]  > report_reg2reg.txt
report_timing -from [all_registers] -to [all_outputs]    > report_reg2output.txt
report_timing -from [all_inputs]    -to [all_outputs]    > report_intput2output.txt
```

-output

```
Warning: cell 'u_phase_sub17/p_reg[6]' is of the wrong type. (UID-119)
Warning: cell 'u_phase_sub17/p_reg[8]' is of the wrong type. (UID-119)
Warning: cell 'u_phase_sub17/p_reg[9]' is of the wrong type. (UID-119)
Warning: cell 'u_phase_sub17/p_reg[10]' is of the wrong type. (UID-119)
Warning: cell 'u_phase_sub17/p_reg[11]' is of the wrong type. (UID-119)
Warning: cell 'u_phase_sub17/p_reg[12]' is of the wrong type. (UID-119)
Warning: cell 'u_phase_sub17/p_reg[13]' is of the wrong type. (UID-119)
Warning: cell 'u_phase_sub8/p_reg[3]' is of the wrong type. (UID-119)
Warning: cell 'u_phase_sub8/p_reg[4]' is of the wrong type. (UID-119)
Warning: cell 'u_phase_sub8/p_reg[7]' is of the wrong type. (UID-119)
Warning: ...13357 additional objects are of the wrong type. (UID-119)
Warning: Ignoring all 13367 objects in collection '_sel29' because they are not of type pin, port, net, clock, or ge
Error: Value for list '-from' must have 1 elements. (CMD-036)
0
```

Did I use that commands correctly? I only expected it to make bunch of the below timing lists.

```
  Startpoint: i_f0[2] (input port clocked by clk)
  Endpoint: trad_28_reg[68]
            (rising edge-triggered flip-flop clocked by clk)
  Path Group: clk
  Path Type: max
  
  
  Point                                    Incr       Path
  -----------------------------------------------------------
  clock clk (rise edge)                    0.00       0.00
  clock network delay (ideal)              0.00       0.00
  input external delay                     0.10       0.10 f
  data arrival time                                   7.41 
  ...
  clock clk (rise edge)                    7.80       7.80
  clock network delay (ideal)              0.00       7.80
  clock uncertainty                       -0.05       7.75
  library setup time                      -0.05       7.70
  data required time                                  7.70
  -----------------------------------------------------------
  data required time                                  7.70
  data arrival time                                  -7.41
  -----------------------------------------------------------
  slack (MET)                                         0.29
```

Comment: I tried myself. It seems that Design Compiler requires `-data_pins` switch, however PrimeTime does not. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @ahmedus Thanks I think it works. and mostly from reg to output 
 path have no path report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `all_registers` command can be used to get a collection of sequential cells. The basic use of it is not different from `all_inputs` and `all_outputs` commands.

The 4 timing reports may be generated as follows.

1. `report_timing -from [all_inputs]               -to [all_registers -data_pins]`
2. `report_timing -from [all_registers -data_pins] -to [all_registers -data_pins]`
3. `report_timing -from [all_registers -data_pins] -to [all_outputs]`
4. `report_timing -from [all_inputs]               -to [all_outputs]`

Note: PrimeTime supports that command as well as Design Compiler, but `-data_pins` (or `-clock_pins`) switch is mandatory for Design Compiler only.

Answer (score 0):

For Synopsys Primetime...

report_timing -start_end_type reg_to_reg

report_timing -start_end_type in_to_reg

report_timing -start_end_type reg_to_out

report_timing -start_end_type in_to_out